# How to programmatically update an input inside shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, web-component

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/5zrwdjy7/2/

I'm trying to automate keystrokes using a script inside Cypress, but the target website uses web components as inputs. The input elements are nested inside **shadow dom** therefor.

I am trying to trigger the input event as per a regular input as follows:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input')
input.value = 'new value'
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

Nothing happens, the value remains unchanged and there is no text displayed in the input. Is it possible to programmatically update input inside shadow dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the shadow encapsulates details of a component, it prevents regular traversal of the DOM. To access it:

1. Find the web component available in the light DOM
2. Traverse its shadow DOM:

```
const lightComponent = document.querySelector('web-component')
const shadowInput = lightComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('input')
shadowInput.value = 'shadow value'
shadowInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

**Source:** https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-events

### Example

```js
// Create shadow dom inside <input-container>
customElements.define('input-container', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadow.innerHTML = `<div><input type="text" /></div>`;
  }
});

// Programmatically update input value inside shadow DOM
const lightComponent = document.querySelector('input-container')
const shadowInput = lightComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('input')
shadowInput.value = 'Shadow value'
shadowInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

```html
<body>
  <label>Input inside shadow DOM</label>
  <input-container></input-container>
</body>
```

Comment: Minor note: You can write: ``this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `<div><input type="text" /></div>`` because attachShadow(...) *sets* **and** *returns* ``this.shadowRoot``. But not with ``mode:'closed'``, and you code won't work then either.. because you can't get the shadowRoot of ``closed`` components.